# AdMob Codes Getting them Right

Tags: android, admob

I am in the process of changing over from test codes to real life Admob codes in my Google Play Android App.

I think I have most of them figured out, but not all. The ones I am really unsure about are at the bottom.

**1. Initialising:**

```
MobileAds.initialize(m_Context, myAppId);
```

The `myAppId` is what AdMob calls the AppId. **Is this correct?**

It starts like `"ca-app-pub-7..."`.

**2. Banner Ads**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="XXX"/>
```

The `XXX` is what AdMob calls the Banner Ad UnitId. **Is this correct?**

It starts like `"ca-app-pub-7..."`.

**3. Interstitial Ads**

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(m_Context);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(adIdInterstitial);
```

The `adIdInterstitial` string is what AdMob calls the Interstitial UnitId. **Is this correct?**

It starts like `"ca-app-pub-7..."`.

**4. The EU privacy thing.**

Using `implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'` you need to call:

```
ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(m_Context);
    String[] publisherIds = {adManagerNetworkCode};
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
    ... etc
```

I have absoltely no idea what the string `adManagerNetworkCode` is. **Can someone tell me what this is?**

**5. My phone's test device Id.**

In my code I have a string called `myDeviceIdForTestConsent` from my phone which I add to code like so:

```
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(myDeviceIdForTestConsent) // Todo: Remove in Release build
                .build());
```

**Can I leave this in for release?**

**Is this the thing that AdMod see so I can keep on testing my code, but they do not unfairly pay me money when I am just testing? If that is the case surely I leave this in?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are correct, and the AppId is the same for testing and production.
2. & 3. You are correct, there are special test UnitAdIds for each type of ad unit (found in the AdMob documentation). The production UnitAdIds can be found when you create those ad units in your AdMob account.
3. The adManagerNetworkCode is the publisherId for your AdMob account. You can find that id on the settings page of your AdMob account.
   https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2784578
   https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent
4. Remove '.addTestDevice(myDeviceIdForTestConsent)'. You do not want your users to see test ads or have any issues receiving ads.